# how split single row to multiple column in python?

Tags: python, split

I read txt file(in eg, test.txt) using

```
read_dat = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter="\t")
```

and the file format of the test.txt is as follows:

```
1.3e-002  1.2e-002  1.13e-002  1.425e-003  1.54e-002
```

and this file has 100 rows of 5 columned data..

After file read, I checked the shape of read_dat like

```
print(read_dat.shape)
```

I expected the result of (100, 5),

but the result is (100, 1)

How can I read the above data correctly...??

Previously thanks..

Comment: Have you checked that the delimiter is indeed a tabstop or is it a space?

Comment: try `read_dat = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: Thank you EdChum.  "delim_whitespace=True" solve the problem..!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that delimiter is indeed a tabulator? In the specified row of test.txt the delimiter is a space. Try maybe `read_dat = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter="\t")`